# .htaccess: Error when using with facebook share link

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls, facebook-share

I have created a `.htaccess` file for my site in order to simplify its URLs. The entire .htaccess reads as follows (*and works as desired*)(Improvements thanks to [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)) :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The only issue I'm facing now is that the facebook share link (that appears on each news article page eg. news/3) gives an error: specifically, clicking on it generates a Server Error 500 page instead of the facebook share window.

[image]

The details of the Server Error 500 read:

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexperiment‌​%2Fprefinalkoh%2Fnews%3Fid%3D6. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

**Do note**: am not able to get Apache error log details for this for some reason even though I set `display_errors = On` `display_startup_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`

The exact fb sharelink that appears on the `news.php` is as follows:

```
        <a href="#" 
          onclick="
            window.open(
              'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
              'facebook-share-dialog', 
              'width=626,height=436'); 
            return false;">
          Share on Facebook
        </a>
```

What can I do to fix this issue - given that I need to have those statements in the .htaccess, while also requiring the fb share link working. My understanding is the facebook link is not 'getting' the cleaned-up link of the current page to be shared & probably a condition needs to be put into the .htaccess?

Would appreciate any help on how to address this.

**RESOLUTION**: This issue was resolved when as suggested by [Mike Rockett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1626250/mike-rockett) in comments, I shifted my project from localhost to liveserver.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the error is being thrown from Facebook as the crawler cannot reach your localhost. The crawler expects a `200 OK` response from the server. So, your sharer button/link should work when you push the website to a domain.

Comment: @Mike Rockett - yes, but there is no such error when the .htaccess is blank - am putting up an image of how it looked before the .htaccess edits.

Comment: or when I put in the url with new.php, rather than news

Comment: Well then I'm befuddled, giving consideration to the fact that Facebook is throwing the server error, and not your localhost. What I'm gathering is that Facebook is not sending the response body back, and so the browser generates its own view for the error. This is why you do not see anything in your Apache error logs - your server is nott throwing that error at all.

Comment: I've also noticed from the error that you're trying to share `http://localhost/experiment‌​/prefinalkoh/news?id=6`, but that doesn't match up to your expected URI, which is either `news/<id>` or `news.php?id=<id>`.

Comment: @Mike Rockett - turns out it worked when I shifted the code to live server - thanks for that!